# Delegation Event Model in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time understanding the DEM (Delegation Event Model) in Java. After reading [this question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989005/delegation-example-regarding-java-context) I didn't get the explanation I needed.

What are the motivations for using DEM?

My observations in the examples I've seen are:

- There is a model with a list of listeners.
- That model also has a methods like `fireThisOrThat()` that are called from other methods like `addThisOrThat`.

I will get this on an upcoming exam, that's why I need to understand it and how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegation means a source generates an event and sends it to one or more listeners.

Java Swing is an excellent example of delegation.  A Swing object, like a `JButton`, will generate events.  In the example of a `JButton`, an event would be that the button image receives a left click (the button is pressed).

Any number of other objects can listen to the `JButton`.  This allows one or more event actions to take place as a result of the `JButton` event.

Suppose you have a `JTextArea`.  You can have a listener on the `JButton` such that when the `JButton` fires a left mouse click event, the `JTextArea` listener edits the text and writes the text to a database.  In other words, you push (left click) a button on the screen, and the text in a `JTextArea` is written to a database.

By using delegation, the `JButton` and the `JTextArea` aren't coupled together.  You could replace the `JTextArea` with another Swing component, and the Swing components would still work together.

Answer (score 0):

In Delegation Event Model, a source generates an event and sends it to one or more listeners. Here, listener waits until it receives an event. Once the listener receives an event, it processes the event and then returns.
The advantage of this design is that the application logic that processes events is clearly separated from the user interface that generates those events.

In the delegation event model, listener must register with a source in order to receive an event notification. The advantage of this is that the notifications are sent only to those listeners that want to receive them.