# Why Delegation doesn't facilitate run time Polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, runtime, delegation

I'm new to this topic called Delegation .So I'm referring this article on [Delegation](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=27916). And there is a line in the article

> delegation is not directly supported by most popular object-oriented languages, and it doesn’t facilitate dynamic polymorphism.

So my question is why it doesn't facilitate Dynamic polymorphism .Is there any example to prove it?

Comment: If you look at [an example of delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989060/5761558), you'll probably answer the question yourself. In the linked answer, delegation is implemented with the `Boss` class. Contrast that to `Boss` extending `Secretary`.